# Cuando ejecuto el comando "help" en Git Bash me da el error "cmd: command not found"

Tags: windows, cmd, git-bash

Cuando escribo:

```
git config --help
```

Git Bash me da el error:

> ```
> /usr/bin/start: line 8: com: command not found
> ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes C:\Program Files\Git\cmd en tu PATH ?

Comment: como verifico eso ?

Comment: En las variables de entorno de tu sistema.

Comment: ¿Sabes como verificar si lo tienes en el path?

Comment: no tengo idea como se hace eso , porfa ayuda

Comment: échale un ojo a este enlace: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1704 . En internet tienes muchos tutoriales que te enseñan a añadir los binarios al PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede ser por que no seleccionaste la opción de añadir al Path cuando instalaste git u ocurre algo mal en la instalacion.

Para verificarlo:

1. Ve al panel de control
2. Sistema y seguridad
3. Sistema
4. Configuración Avanzada del sistema (Menú superior a la izquierda)
5. En la pestaña de opciones avanzadas
6. Al final un boton muestra la palabra "Variables de entorno"
7. **Variables del sistema**
8. Verifica la que tiene por nombre path
9. Observa si en la lista aparecen

   ```
   C:\Archivos de Programa\Git\bin\git.exe
   ```

   y
       C:\Archivos de Programa\Git\cmd
10. De no ser asi debes agregarlo en nuevo, solo debes copiar las rutas que te indique en el paso anterior, por lo general esas son las
    rutas donde se instala el git por defecto.

En todo caso y para ahorrarte molestias te recomiendo reinstalarlo y al momento que la opción del path aparezca cerciorarte que esta marcada.

Comment: mm tienes razón no se encuentra esa variable ahora que nombre le pongo a cada variable osea para C:\Archivos de Programa\Git\bin\git.exe y para C:\Archivos de Programa\Git\cmd ??

Comment: Si así es, en todo caso , te recomiendo reinstalar el git y marcar la opción del path

Comment: Amigo revisa nuevamente el paso a paso me hizo falta uno, saludos..